# Insert multiple records in single call

Tags: javascript, azure

So I'm trying to insert an array of records of length to Azure Table. I'm on New Azure portal, and all the help I found was for old one.

New Azure Portal's Script page looks like

[image: Azure Portal]

I've tried to override the insert method as following:

```
var table = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
table.insert(function (context) {
  
  all_answers = context.item.answers;
  console.log(all_answers[0]);
  return context.execute();
});
```

Log shows the following object:

```
    { id: '',
      userid: '0029C048-B8A0-42AE-B8F8-2B9402D69EEF',
      createdate: '2016-01-30 00:40:18',
      questionid: 1,
      choiceid: 0 
    }
```

How can I insert all records of array in Table?
Anticipated Thanks